# Google Cloud add sensitive scope to production

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add a new sensitive scope to my verified production project.  I added the new scope but I do not understand how to create the new video to submit as when I login it says "This app is blocked" Is there another way I should be doing this?  I do not see anyway to do development work off a production project?

[Blocked Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZGqz.jpg)

Comment: Once your OAuth app is approved and you modify it with new scopes, you must reverify.

Comment: Correct my project's OAuth apps are currently approved. I need to add more. However when I enable the new API scopes my app shows it needs verification.  When I move my new web code that uses the new API's to the production keys I am not able to log in anymore to record how I am using the new API's to create a video that is needed to verify the new sensitive apps?

Comment: I was expecting to see the "Unverified app screen" not a blocked screen.

Comment: This is not a programming question that is on-topic for Stackoverflow. You need to contact Google Cloud support.

Comment: Thanks John.  I see I don't have a support role. "To access Role-Based Support, please contact your Support Account Administrator or Organization Administrator."  I will have to see who has this role in my organization to contact them.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a vendor support/policy problem.